# OutputDebugString error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, outputdebugstring

I use:

```
OutputDebugString(L"My error");
```

in Visual Studio 2010, but instead of displaying "My error", I get just an "ERROR" in the window.

[image]

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Uh, are you displaying it in a status bar? I can't tell where that's showing up. In Visual Studio, this should display in the Output or Immediate Window. Is that where it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're explicitly passing an UNICODE string, I'd suggest you also explicitly call `OutputDebugStringW()`.

Otherwise, if the `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol is not defined in your compilation unit, the ANSI version of the function (`OutputDebugStringA()`) would end up being called with an UNICODE string, which it does not support, and it *should* result in a compilation error.

**EDIT:** You cannot use [OutputDebugString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362.aspx) to write a string in your application's status bar. `OutputDebugString()` only sends the string you pass to the debugger.

You have to use the appropriate API to write text to the status bar instead. In your case, [wxStatusBar::SetStatusText()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxstatusbar.html#wxstatusbarsetstatustext) should do the trick.

Comment: You *should* get a compiler error if you pass a Unicode string to a function that is expecting an ANSI string.

Comment: @Cody, indeed, normally the compiler *should* be able to tell `char *` from `wchar_t *`, but it's C++, so implicit conversion constructors and cast operators *can* mess with that, I suppose. Answer updated, thank you for your comment :)

Comment: It still doesn`t work!I checked that UNICODE preprocessor symbol is  defined and I call OutputDebugStringW (this is done by macro,where OutputDebugString is defined as OutputDebugStringW if UNICODE is defined :    #ifdef UNICODE
#define OutputDebugString  OutputDebugStringW
#else
#define OutputDebugString  OutputDebugStringA
#endif // !UNICODE

Comment: @Yakov, does your program compile at all? If it does, can you tell us exactly where you're looking for the `My error` message?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi I display it in the status bar.Before OutputDebugStringW run it is written OK there.After the run it changes to     ERROR,instead of "My error"

Comment: @Yakov, did you write code to capture `OutputDebugString()`'s output and send it to the status bar? `OutputDebugString()` only talks to the debugger by default.

Comment: @ Frédéric Hamidi - probably no.I use object of my class which derives from wxGLCanvas to display the message.From this object I call some error reporting function that I wrote.The only thing this function  does  - run OutputDebugString with the argument as described above.